# Cannot read property 'drag' of undefined D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I am beginner with D3 and I am trying to drag with mouse a rectangle but actually I experience some troubles.

If I define var drag before to call it get this error: Cannot read property 'drag' of undefined

If I define var drag after calling it, I get a different error: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
But actually, searching on stackoverflow I read that to solve this probl I need to define the var drag before to call it and I am on a loop.

Below you can see my code. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var fullAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
var arc2 = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(195)
            .outerRadius(200)
            .startAngle(0.18)
            .endAngle(fullAngle / 1.02);

var svgContainer = d3.select("#container")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("border", "1px solid");

var group1 = svgContainer.append("g");
var group2 = svgContainer.append("g");
group2.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc2())
    .attr("fill", "blue")

group1.attr("transform", "translate(" + 200 + "," + 200 + ")");
group2.attr("transform", "translate(" + 250 + "," + 250 + ")");

var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 150)
          .attr("y", 50)
          .attr("width", 30)
          .attr('class', 'rectangle')
          .attr("height", 70)
          .call(drag)

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', function () {
        var obj = svgContainer.append("rect")
        dragMove(this, obj, 'rect')
    });
});



    function setPoints(obj, prop) {
        obj[prop] = []
        var k = 0
        d3.selectAll('.rect')
            .each(function() {
                var c = d3.select(this)
                var cX = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).translate[0]
                var cY = d3.transform(c.attr('transform')).translate[1]
                obj[prop].push({
                    x: cX,
                    y: cY,
                    index: k++
                })
            })
    }

      function dragMove(rectangle, obj, prop) {
          var x = d3.event.x
          var y = d3.event.y
          setPoints(obj, prop)
          d3.select(rectangle).attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')
          $scope.$apply()
      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using d3 v4 in your code.

`d3.behavior.drag()` is changed to `d3.drag` you function should be like this and declared before usage

```
var drag = d3.drag().on("drag", function () {
         d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); // silence other listeners
          dragMove(this, obj, 'points')
     })
```

Implement your dragMove function to continue See this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/206/)

Comment: I have rearranged my code and now drag is working. I added in my snippet the functions I call to drag the rectangle (setPoints and dragMove) but actually when I click on the rectangle, it moves to right uncorrectly

Comment: @PierpaoloErcoli What yopur expected output or ahat are you trying to do may be that definition can help

Comment: @PierpaoloErcoli If you were just trying to follow drag path its here https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/208/

Comment: neither fiddle nor idea nothing works.. though v3 to v4 changes are there

Comment: @ThinkTank did you see https://jsfiddle.net/n4m1r8nb/208/ drag works here

Comment: hi thanks its working for now in js nut i'm trying same thing in angular not able to accomplish it.

Comment: @ThinkTank Can you provide a sample code may be in fiddle or stackblitz ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954149/d3-v4-tree-is-not-draggable-on-initialization-with-anugular7

Answer (score 4):

You are using D3 v4, and like many other things, the drag behavior has been renamed. From the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md):

> The drag behavior d3.behavior.drag has been renamed to d3.drag.

You need to adjust your code for this renaming.

```
var drag = d3.drag().on('drag', function () {
    dragMove(this, obj, 'points')
});
```

Since the implementation did also change, there may be other changes required to make it actually work. This however is not clear from the code you provided and will well be worth another question.

Comment: I have rearranged my code and now drag is working. I added in my snippet the functions I call to drag the rectangle (setPoints and dragMove) but actually when I click on the rectangle, it moves to right uncorrectly

Comment: @PierpaoloErcoli Please re-read the last paragraph of my answer: That was to be expected. But as I said, that should be posted as a new question.